# Big O-Notation complexity order

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have read about the Big-O complexity order. On the internet it said the order is:

> O(1) < O(log n) < O(n) < O(n log n) < O(n^2) < O(n^3) < O (2^n) < O
>   (10^n)

Now I want to sort these O-Notations in their complexity order going from the lowest to the highest.

```
a: O(π^e n^2)   
b: O(n+n^2/√n^3)  
c: O((1/10^100)n!+5n^2)  
d: O(25√9n)  
e: O(log(n^n)
```

Is the order e, d, a, b correct? I am not sure where c belongs.

Comment: Hint: google "stirling approximation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that mathematically speaking, I've never heard about a properly defined order relationship on the image of the O operator, so when you're saying `O(1) < O(log n)`, as far as I know there is no mathematical definition for it and it only means that an algorithm performing with a complexity of `O(1)` will be slower (for large problems) than an algorithm with a complexity of `O(n)`.

Now to answer your question, let's simplify all expressions:

```
a: O(π^e n^2)           <=> O(n^2)      (a constant factor doesn't affect the nature of complexity itself although it will impact running time)
b: O(n+n^2/√n^3)        <=> O(n^2/√n^3) (eliminating a term that evolves slower than the other term) 
                        <=> O(√n)       (simplifying expression)
c: O((1/10^100)n!+5n^2) <=> O(n!)       (eliminating a term that evolves slower than the other term and removing constant factors)
d: O(25√9n)             <=> O(n)        (removing constant factors)
e: O(log(n^n))          <=> O(n log(n)) (simplifying expression)
```

Now it becomes clear that the "order", from faster to slower, will be: `b, d, e, a, c`